# Шаблон Data Mapper обработка большого количества данных

Tags: php, шаблоны-проектирования, data-mapper

Изучаю шаблон **Data Mapper**, и основной вопрос: как коллекции справляются с обработкой большого количества объектов (преобразованных записей из таблицы - в моем случае это около 2-3 тысяч).

Подробнее, что я делал. Читаю "*Мэтт Зандстра. Объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования.*". Он пишет, что "*...если в итоге возвращается множество из 1000 объектов, его обработка окажется чрезмерно затратной...*". В качестве способа решения используется коллекция, реализующая интерфейс Iterator. Насколько я понял, идея в том, чтобы в коллекции хранился массив строк, и только по необходимости, при запросе клиента, эта строка преобразовывалась в объект. Отрывок класса Collection:

```php
abstract class Collection implements \Iterator ...
// ...
protected $raw = array(); // массив данных
private $objects = array(); // массив объектов - пустой при создании
// ...
public function getRow($num){
    if(array_key_exists($num, $this->objects)){
        return $this->objects[$num];
    }
    
    if(array_key_exists($num, $this->raw)){
        $obj = $this->mapper->createObject($this->raw[$num]);
        $this->objects[$num] = $obj;
        return $this->objects[$num];
    }
    //...
}
//...
```

Теперь, где-то в представлении, я могу использовать эту коллекцию как массив. Например, конкретная задача - вывести прайс картриджей, их около 2000, и все надо показать на одной странице. Получается, что я получаю коллекцию CartridgesCollection и в цикле вывожу ее:

```
<?php foreach($CartridgesCollection as $cartridge){ ?>
    <div><?= $cartridge->getName() ?></div>
    // do something else
<?php } ?>
```

Вроде все понятно, но как решается проблема "затратности обработки"? Ведь пока я массив вывожу, я так же создаю свои 2000 объектов. Насколько я понимаю: так как в `$CartridgesCollection` изначально не куча объектов, это и дает необходимую оптимизацию?

Comment: Вряд ли вам нужно выводить все 2000 записей на странице, лучше сделать пагинацию и постраничный вывод с фильтрацией. Это будет реализоваться через итератор, где вы сможете выводить только товары на текущей странице, и двигаясь с итератором вперёд (хотя это не совсем итератор, а pagination - постраничный вывод). Оптимизацией в этом случае будет маппинг ограниченного страницей число товаров.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov да нет, именно нужно все, ситуация не совсем обычная. В моем случае  прайс картриджей  - нужен полностью, чтобы по нему можно было хоть по CTRL-F найти свою модель, иначе в нем смысла нет. По 20 страницам пагинации щелкать в надежде найти именно конкретную модель - занятие так себе.

Comment: собственно, https://www.copygroup.ru/zapravka-kartridzhej/HP/

Comment: Именно поэтому я и упомянул фильтрацию, чтобы не было необходимости делать поиск по странице таким образом. В большинстве каталогов она есть, и достаточно обширная по основным параметрам товаров. В вашем случае вы можете закэшировать сконвертированные данные чтобы не делать это каждый раз. Не знаю применимо ли то, о чем говорит Мэтт в вашем случае если вам нужны все объекты.